# How to check if a point is snapped to a line in QGIS

Tags: qgis, topology

I have two vector classes, sg_point and sg_line. Any sg_point HAS to be snapped to a sg_line. I should not find errors if I use snapping correctly, but in case there are errors how do I check in QGIS?

I have tried select by locaction, but no matter what option I use, either I get all points (useless) or no points (also useless). I cannot get either only the points that are snapped nor only the points that are not snapped to a sg_line instance.

What am I doing wrong?

I am using Pisa 2.10.1

UPDATE - 
I have tested many configurations. It seems to me that select by location only works when the snapped point is not a vertice. When it is snapped to a segment, it is not selected. Is this working as expected, or is this a bug?

Comment: It looks like a bug.